# Prob. 5, Sec. 4.5, in Kreyszig's Functional Analysis Book: The adjoint of the composite of two bounded linear operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be normed spaces, either all real or all complex. Let $T \colon X \longrightarrow Y$ and $S \colon Y \longrightarrow  Z$ be bounded linear operators. Let $X^\prime$, $Y^\prime$, and $Z^\prime$ denote the dual spaces of  (i.e. the normed spaces of all the bounded linear functionals defined on ) $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, respectively. Let $T^\times \colon Y^\prime \longrightarrow X^\prime$ and $S^\times \colon Z^\prime \longrightarrow Y^\prime$ denote the adjoint operators of $T$ and $S$, respectively. By definition, the operator $T^\times \colon Y^\prime \longrightarrow X^\prime$ is defined by $$ \left( \, T^\times (g) \, \right) (x) = g\big( T (x) \big) \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in X$$ for all $g \in Y^\prime$.

This $T^\times$ is a bounded linear operator with $$\left\lVert T^\times \right\rVert = \lVert T \rVert.$$

How to show that
$$\big( S \circ T \big)^\times = T^\times \circ S^\times?$$

My Attempt:

> Let $h \in Z^\prime$. We need to show that $$ \big( S \circ T \big)^\times (h) = \left( T^\times \circ S^\times \right) (h).\tag{1} $$

> Since $S \circ T \colon X \longrightarrow  Z$, therefore $\big( S \circ T \big)^\times \colon Z^\prime \longrightarrow X^\prime$.

> Thus, in order to show that the (1) above holds, we must show that
> $$ \left( \, \big( S \circ T \big)^\times (h) \, \right) (x) = \left( \, \left( T^\times \circ S^\times \right) (h) \, \right) (x) \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in X. \tag{2} $$

> But we note that
> $$
> \begin{align}
>  \left( \, \big( S \circ T \big)^\times (h) \, \right) (x) &= h \big( \, \big( S \circ T \big)(x) \, \big) \\
> &= h\big( \,  S \big( T(x) \big) \, \big) \\
> &= \left( \, S^\times (h) \, \right)\big( T(x) \big) \\
> &= T^\times \left( \, S^\times (h) \, \right)(x) \\
> &= \left( \, \left( T^\times \circ S^\times \right)(h) \, \right)(x).
>  \end{align} $$

Is this reasoning correct? If not, then where does the problem lie?

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me.

Note that it might be more clear to use the functional notation $f(x) := \langle x, f \rangle$ here, which Kreyszig does not use. Using this notation:

$$ \langle x, (S T)^{\times} z' \rangle = \langle S T x, z' \rangle = \langle Tx, S^{\times} z' \rangle = \langle x, T^{\times} S^{\times} z' \rangle $$

whenever $x \in X$ and $z' \in Z'$. Thus $(S T)^{\times} = T^{\times} S^{\times}$.